# Publish Artifacts task do not publish code on file share path

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Publish artifacts task configured as file share path but it doesn't publish any code throwing error:

> [error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Unable to create directory '\INDLBCKPF1MXWMV\Publish\AshishVerma-ASP.NET
>
> Core-CI\drop'. Unable to verify the directory exists:
> '\INDLBCKPF1MXWMV\Publish\AshishVerma-ASP.NET Core-CI\drop'. If
> directory is a file share, please verify the share name is correct,
> the share is online, and the current process has permission to access
> the share.

Comment: Are you using a private agent or a hosted agent?

Comment: Hi Daniel Mann,   I am using hosted agent 'Azure Pipelines', not found any solution on internet for this error, Can you help me plz

Comment: @Ashish Verma Did you tried below answers? Any updates for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the hosted agent. The hosted agent does not have access to your on prem network.

Publish the artifacts to Azure DevOps instead of to a file share.

Comment: Ok, Daniel.... Can its possible with create private agent for windows, if you can suggest me any reference link so it will be better for me.

Comment: I have created private agent for publish artifacts into shared location but now i am getting here different error as-                                                                   
Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '\\INDLBCKPF1MXWMV\Publish\Demo-ASP.NET Core-CI'

Comment: Why are you determined to publish to a file share? You **do not need to do that**. Publishing to Azure DevOps is much easier and has no downside.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of what **Publishing build artifacts** task actually does is to copy the contents in artifacts folder you defined in `Path to publish` field to a place in azure devops server.

So you can just have a try using a **copy** task to copy the contents in artifacts folder to your share file path.
There are multiple copy tasks available.

For example: **Remote Copy** task and **[Windows machine file copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops)** task. You can just replace Publishing build artifacts task with one of the copy task.

Hope you find above helpful and good luck!

Comment: None of that addresses the actual problem, which is that the hosted agent can't access on-premise resources.

Comment: Thanks Daniel & Levi Lu-MSFT, i have completed it by created Private Agent for windows OS and in release pipeline taking the Windows machine file copy to copy the published code on local system path.

Comment: @Ashish Verma That's great you work it out. You can post your solution and accept it, so that others whose encounter the same issue can refer to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have completed it by created Private Agent for windows OS in project settings section with enter new agent name and followed the steps suggested by Azure to activate newly created agent, if it will not activate then it will show as offline status otherwise it will be shown as green status. Then go for CI pipeline to configure build process and at last configure CD pipeline to copy the publish code on local system path by using Windows machine file copy task.